# Create an iteration of carousel cards upon clicking on next button (CYPRESS)

Tags: cypress, each

Guys I am trying to make an .each() iteration of carousel cards. So what I am trying to do is that I land on page and then I see carousel and I press on ">" button and new cards pops up (I verify it is visible) then I press on ">" again to see the new card popping up and so on. I am still learning so don't know which code to provide for you. I will leave CSS selectors here , please help me :)

whole carousel content - .carousel-content
the ">" button - .next-btn
the new specific card that pops up ( for every card is different ) - .new-card(1)

Comment: Can you provide your exact HTML? I'll write up an answer, but it won't be using any HTML specific to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your carousel does not update the total amount of cards that exist, we can easily use `.each()` to validate each card that exists.

```js
cy.get('.new-card')
  // `.each()` allows us to yield a specific element, the index of the element, and the entire array of elements.
  .each(($el, index, $list) => {
    cy.wrap($el).should('exist'); // validations on the existing card    
    cy.get('.next-btn').then(($btn) => {
      if ($btn.is(":disabled")) {
        return 
      } else {
        cy.wrap($btn).click();
    });
  });
```

I made additional assumptions that you would validate a card before clicking the button. If this is incorrect, simply reverse those parts of my answer. I also made an assumption that we wouldn't want to click the button on the last iteration.

Comment: man you are the best! it worked very nice but it still gave an error since it tried to click the button after the last slide I think? here it is : Timed out retrying after 4050ms: cy.click() failed because this element is disabled: <button class="next-button...... use force:true to disable error checking. so what happened is that once the last card popped out the button ">" disappeared. but other than that that code worked the best!

Comment: after using cy.wrap I changed the code to cy.get('.next-btn').then(($btn) => {
        if ($btn.is(":disabled")) {
          return
        } else {
          cy.wrap($btn).click()
        }
      })

Comment: and it worked surprisingly

Comment: Yeah, I figured something like that might happen. I'll update my answer to include your findings.

Comment: man,  regardless you helped tons! I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: by the way, I noticed it works of regardless if I write if (index < $list.length - 1) or not, is that how it should be?

Comment: I think your check for if the element is disabled or not essentially renders that part moot. I was initially thinking that we could infer the enabled/disabled state by checking if it was the last item in the list, but I think I like your way better. I'll remove that as well.

Comment: hey bro, I know Im asking for too much but is there any chance to get your contact and maybe get on zoom call so you could help me and teach how to do the specific test? the code you wrote above works but apparently its no what people who asked me to write it were looking for and I tried everything and I guess nobody else could help me with that. thank you for any answer.